# Submitted Symfony form return wrong field value

Tags: forms, symfony4

I am doing some tests with `Symfony 4` Forms and the answer to my question might be very simple but I am really confused right now and I need fresh eye to understand the following strange behavior. 
Here is the context : I have a page `/edit` which handle a form for an entity named `Promoter` in a very classic way but after passing the validation I am generating and setting a randon firstname then flush the entity (which is updated with the new data form the form and the new firstname), and after instead of redirecting to another page, I return to the same page with the new `Promoter` entity.

My expectation is the see the new generated firstname but in fact it shows the old one(the one send by the form to the controller) and I cannot understand why? Can somebody has a clue?

I should add that data in db are correctly updated.

The Controller code is:

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="promoter_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Promoter $promoter
     * @return Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Promoter $promoter): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PromoterFormType::class, $promoter);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $firstname = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'),0,5);
            $promoter->setFirstname( $firstname );
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($promoter);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('promoter/edit.html.twig', [
            'promoter' => $promoter,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when you post your form, you create the new one before updating your 'promoter'. You should try to reload your page after submitting your form.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $firstname = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'),0,5);
    $promoter->setFirstname( $firstname );
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($promoter);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your PromoterFormType class have a field for firstname? Because otherwise it could override your newly set Firstname.

If so fix:
In PromoterFormType

```
->add('firstname')
```

needs the option: 'mapped' => false.
Or simple delete it from the formType.

[More info](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html)

If not can you show us the FormType and the Promoter Entity?
Hope this helps for you!